# Where is email stored on an Android device?

Tags: android, email

In an Android device: **Where is Email stored** ? Please can anybody tell me?

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Noo pls It's regarding Programing Concern..

Answer (score 6):

There are many, many email applications for Android. Each stores email in its own way. The "standard" email applications (Email and Gmail) do not support third parties manipulating stored emails.

Comment: Yhanx CommonsWare for Reply...
Like when we access Gmail once and if off the Internet Connection ..then stil Email are Stored in the Androide Device..that's y I asked..
Can  anybody tel me where please
Yhnx

Comment: Gmail is a proprietary application. You cannot access the stored emails. Period.

Comment: Thanx CoomonWare but when I use Emulator after SHutoff Internet Connection..then still Mail are avail there..not directly from server..but they stored somewher in the device..

Comment: @SHubham: They'll be stored in some unreadable format. They aren't just plain text files that you can open and read like a normal email.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/gmail-account/conversation-id/messages")
```